# How to lower Renderer Utilization?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, scenekit

I am having sever performance issues with a SceneKit game. Total vertices count 4000. Renderer Utilization is 100% on ipad3, framerate 16fps, even though Tiler utilization is only about 8%. This is screenshot from  OPENGL ES Analysis.

[image]

This is the entire code that is used to specify what the object should look like. As you can see there is no custom shaders. Just a box that falls on the floor because of physics applied to it. Textures and 2 lights are applied in the .scn file.  Everything is simple, basic but the performance is terrible. How do I lower Renderer Utilization on the device? I am guessing some default settings that sceneKit uses aren't suitable for my app and cause severe performance problems. Which one should I double check?

```
//called in viewDidLoad:
 func setupScene(){
            scene = SCNScene(named: "GameScene.scn")
            sceneView.scene = scene
            sceneView.delegate = self
            scene.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
            scene.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
            scene.physicsWorld.speed = 1.8
            sceneView.jitteringEnabled = true
            sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = false


        sceneView.antialiasingMode = SCNAntialiasingMode.None
        let valueVector: NSValue = NSValue(SCNVector3: SCNVector3Make(0.7, 0.7, 0.7))
        objectNode = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("object", recursively: true)!
        let physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: objectNode, options: [SCNPhysicsShapeTypeKey:SCNPhysicsShapeTypeBoundingBox, SCNPhysicsShapeScaleKey:valueVector])
        objectNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Dynamic, shape: physicsShape)

        let floorNode = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("floor", recursively: true)
        floorNode?.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Static, shape: nil)
     objectNode.categoryBitMask = 1
        floorNode?.categoryBitMask = 1
        objectNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
        floorNode?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
        objectNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
        floorNode?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1

        floorNode?.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.7
        objectNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.7


        }

func speed(velocity:SCNVector3) -> Float
    {
        let dx = Float(velocity.x)
        let dy = Float(velocity.y)
        let dz = Float(velocity.z)
        return sqrtf(dx*dx+dy*dy+dz*dz)
    }
    func angularSpeed(angularSpeed: SCNVector4)->Float{
        let x = angularSpeed.x

        let y = angularSpeed.y
        let z = angularSpeed.z

        return sqrtf(x*x+y*y+z*z)
    }

    func nearlyAtRest(node:SCNNode) -> Bool
    {

        return speed((node.physicsBody?.velocity)!) < 0.05 && ( self.resting == false) && (angularSpeed((node.physicsBody?.angularVelocity)!) < 1)
    }


// PHYSICS CONTACT DELEGATE DELEGATE METHOD
        func renderer(renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didSimulatePhysicsAtTime time: NSTimeInterval) {

      if nearlyAtRest(objectNode) && speed((objectNode.physicsBody?.velocity)!) != 0 {
    print("it stopped")
    }
```

Comment: I'd try `.jitteringEnabled = false`, documentation states jittering shouldn't have much performance impact, but that's easy to confirm. Next I'd look at removing one of your lights to see if this has an impact.

Comment: I'd recommend giving up on Scene Kit in its current form. It's like Unity, you're going to go from one issue to the next, constantly.

Comment: Woa, setting jiitering to false actually did have an impact on performance. A lying apple we got here. removing ambient light had no effect. Do you guys have any experience with baking light maps in SceneKit editor?

Comment: I have an ambient and spot light. Both of them are not moving. They shine on blue SCNFloor among other objects. The floor is not moving too, therefore baking is an option. Whenever I bake light map on floor object, it loses its color and takes over the color of the light. It goes from blue to gray(gray is the color of my lights because white is too bright.) Also all colisions stop working which is kinda weird. What have I missed?

Comment: Interesting about the jittering, I read what it did and figured it must have some impact on rendering. Have you turned off reflection on your SCNFloor (`floor.reflectivity = 0`)? If not, I'm pretty sure it re-renders the scene just for the floor and this could also impact performance. I need to look at baking, I've currently got a static directional light and the fewer lights the better.